# C# Selenium Chrome change homepage

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

i am trying to change chrome default homepage (google tabs) but i didn' t find a working solution.
What i have tried:

```
var _options = new ChromeOptions();
_options.AddUserProfilePreference("homepage", "http://www.example.com");
_options.AddUserProfilePreference("homepage_is_newtabpage", true);
_options.AddUserProfilePreference("session.restore_on_startup", 4);
_options.AddUserProfilePreference("session.startup_urls", new List<string>() { "http://in.gr"});
_options.AddArgument("--homepage=http://in.gr");
var _driver = new ChromeDriver(_options);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can navigate to the page you want to after initializing the WebDriver before you begin the rest of your web automation.

```
...
var _driver = new ChromeDriver(_options);
_driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://in.gr");
```

Hope that is of some help.

Comment: Thanks for your response but navigate is not an option. I am trying to change the default homepage because all extensions load after google default homepage start. For example proxy authentication extension some times need time to load and proxy auth prompt appear on google default homepage.